# Replacing Domain Controller with Server 2022

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2012, domain, domain-controller

We have two Domain Controllers running 2012 R2. I have been given a project to replace these with 2022.
I have just discovered that the Domain Functional Level is still 2008 R2.

I have issues with FRS which i need to solve before i can join 2022 server as a DC.
Would i be correct in assuming the sequence would be

1. Promoting the domain to 2012 R2
2. Addressing the FRS Issue (Switch to DFS)
3. Joining the 2022 Server as a DC
4. Raise the Forest Level

Then i should be able to start building / promoting the 2022 servers and decomissioning the 2012 dc's.

Answer (score 3):

Start by reading the Microsoft documentation. You don't need to raise the functional levels to introduce a Windows Server 2022 Domain Controller, but you do need to migrate SYSVOL from FRS to DFSR.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-ds/active-directory-functional-levels

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/storage/dfs-replication/migrate-sysvol-to-dfsr

Answer (score 1):

The upgrade path is always add a new server as a secondary 2022 domain controller to the domain. The transfer the FSMO roles and demote the old dc.
https://www.petenetlive.com/kb/article/0001790